# ¿Cómo actualizar un queryset utilizando un diccionario pero excluyendo una llave del diccionario?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un `QuerySet` y quiero actualizar cada uno de los objetos empleando un diccionario. Para ello utilizo:

```
for objeto in queryset:
    objeto.update(**diccionario)
    objeto.save()
```

Sin embargo, si se cumple cierta condición, tengo que actualizar los objetos con el diccionario pero no puedo incluir el valor de cierta llave del diccionario, por ejemplo:

```
for objeto in queryset:
    if condicion = True:
        objeto.update(**diccionario)
        objeto.save()
    else:
        objeto.update(**diccionario.exclude('fecha_inicio'))
        objeto.save()
```

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto? En mi caso, si se cumple la condición actualizo el objeto, pero si no se cumple tengo que actualizarlo excepto en el campo `fecha_inicio`.

Comment: debe ser `condicion == True`, si bien con un `if condicion` ya debería valer.

Comment: Podrías dar detalles de la condición_? que estructura tiene? la condición involucra campos de la base de datos_?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es jugar con las condiciones, no tienes que poner el `update` y el `save` dentro del `if`. Puedes sacarlo fuera de la condición de tal manera que la condición solo sirva para actualizar el diccionario:

```
for objeto in queryset:
    if condicion == False:
        diccionario.pop('fecha_inicio')
    objeto.update(**diccionario)
    objeto.save()
```

Observa que estoy haciendo la inversa, es decir, si **no** se cumple la condición entonces quito `fecha_inicio` del diccionario usando `pop()`.

### Actualización

Asumiendo que el diccionario lo creas fuera del loop, entonces cambian un poco las cosas ya que es probable que necesites `fecha_inicio` para algunos objetos y para otros no.

En ese caso puedes guardar el valor fuera del loop y luego, usando una copia del diccionario, puedes ir actualizando de acuerdo a la condición:

```
fecha_inicio = diccionario.pop('fecha_inicio')
for objeto in queryset:
    d = diccionario.copy()
    if condicion == True:
        d.update(fecha_inicio=fecha_inicio)
    objeto.update(**d)
    objeto.save()
```

A la copia del diccionario siempre le faltará `fecha_inicio` y en cada iteración se va a agregar si la condición es verdadera.

Comment: Probablemente sería bueno hacer una copia de `diccionario` por si quiere usar los datos más adelante. Al fin y al cabo, se está eliminando un elemento de la variable _global_.

Comment: @fedorqui cierto, buena observación. He actualizado la respuesta.